# Visa refused - V4.2 (a) (c) - Incorrect Decision

Tags: uk, pakistani-citizens

I have received the refusal latter today apparently the ECO has refused the visa citing reasons due to economic circumstances.
They mentioned that the salary payments were not sourced by the debits to my employers account and gave example for a month; per them the amount deposited into my account on a certain date was not reflected in my employers account debits.  When I checked this after getting home, all the check numbers were reflecting in company’s bank statement - every single one!

Second reason they stated regarding payments being irregular in amount but that could have been easily verified through the pay slips that I had submitted; the variance details for extra payments were mentioned such as overtime, leave encashment OPD payment etc.

I strongly believe they have overlooked these details and made a hasty decision probably it being a "priority visa application"

Is there a way I can make them realize they made a mistake and if they could revisit this decision?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should also consider that you were wrong (not including enough documentation AND explaining what it is the relevance). You have the task to proof things. I recommend that you do again the application, and you let an other person to read and see if it is complete/comprehensible. We all tend to assume too much (immigration officers do not know us and our culture), and we often forget to include some documents, or just read wrongly some questions. It is human. Improving application is usually better than to appeal [appeal are handled by people who know much less about your culture]

Comment: According to the detailed refusal notice, you are self-employed. You don’t seem to have provided any independent documentation (eg latest tax return) to prove your income. Without such corroborating evidence it is difficult for UKVI to be certain that your financial circumstances are as stated in your application.

Comment: If you’re strongly convince they are wrong, reapply. In your application include copious but concise notes showing links between all significant deposits. As someone said, make the application so clear a third party can understand everything without asking questions. Sometimes ECO’s are just plain unreasonable but sometimes they are simply unable to make an approval decision given the limited time they have when things are not totally clear..

Comment: The refusal refers specifically to a deposit on 10 January that they say did not correspond to any salary payment. There might have been others. What was that and did you provide evidence for it?

Answer (score 2):

The refusal letter you received should also have included text telling you that you have no right of appeal in respect of this decision.

Your recourse is to apply again, ensuring that you have addressed the reasons given for refusal. In this case, a simple cover letter explaining the issues as you have outlined them here might suffice. Be polite and to the point.

However, be sure that you fully understood the letter you received before applying again. If you haven't you risk a second refusal and it will become much more difficult to get a visa thereafter.

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) might be useful